# Give some example of quotient topology?

Tags: algebraic-topology

Give some easy example of Quotient topology ?

**My attempt** : I got some example [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/473662/example-of-quotient-topology) But im facing difficulties in understanding the  example

I need some example that is easy to understand

I know the definition of

**Quotient topology** : let $X$ be a topological space and $~$ an equivalence relation on $X$. For every $x \in X$ , denote by $[x]$ its equivalence class .The quotient space  of $X$ modulo $ \sim$ is given by the set

$X/\sim~ =\{[x] : x \in X \}$

we have the projection map $p: X \to /\sim ,x \to [x]$
and we equib $X/\sim$ by the topology

$U\subseteq$ $X/ \sim~$ is open if and only if $p^{-1}(u)$ is an open subset  of $X$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a nice example:  Start with the compact interval $[0,1]$.  "Identify the endpoints" to get a (topological) circle.  This means your equivalence relation is $x \sim y$ iff either $x=y$ or else $\{x,y\} = \{0,1\}$.

Other common ones start with a square $[0,1] \times [0,1]$ and identify the boundaries in certain ways.  Depending on how you identify the points of the boundary, you could get a (topological) sphere, a cylinder, a Möbius band, a torus, a Klein bottle, or other things.